# Can Azure SQL Logins be restricted to specific IPs?

Tags: sql, database, azure, ip, whitelist

In Azure SQL DBs, can SQL Logins be restricted to specific IPs?

We currently use the Azure firewall rules to whitelist IPs and it works fine. But better security to restrict each SQL login to a specific allowable IP list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is no.

I was looking through the official documentation, here:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-firewall-configure/

As you know, you can have multiple logins and you can have multiple IP address (or ranges of IPs) but I haven't seen anything to combine both login and IP to allow/deny access.